# Acumatica REST API - Get Roles Array from Contact/ContactUserInfo

Tags: rest, acumatica

I'm attempting to GET a list of contacts who are assigned to a specific role. If my contact has the user role "Sales Rep", then I'd want to get all Contacts for whom "Sales Rep" is among their roles.

For context, the Contact Model looks like this:

```
{
   id: "7e87d8fc-6d18-4g95-8334-e54b69e2803t",
   ... // additional fields

   UserInfo: { // <-- ContactUserInfo entity
       id: "da1b408e-571c-4896-be61-a02c5f99b1ec",
       ... // additional fields,
       Roles: [] // <-- Roles are stored here as ContactRole entities
   }
}
```

[Screenshot of Contact Model in API Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzsNI.png)

## What I've tried so far:

1. According to the [Integration Development Guide (pg 65)](https://www.acumatica.com/media/2019/05/Acumatica-ERP-2018-R2-Integration-Development-Guide.pdf), linked and detail entities have to be explicitly specified in the expand parameter, so that gives me the following:

   `{{site}}/entity/Default/18.200.001/Contact?$expand=UserInfo/Roles`

   However, this gives me the error:

   `Optimization cannot be performed.The following fields cause the error: UserInfo.Roles.RoleDescription: View Roles has BQL delegate.`

---

2. So I looked into this BQL Delegate issue. According to the [Acumatica wiki](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(4))/Show.aspx?pageid=775ca16b-cba6-4c1d-89d5-c1df7833bfea) (scroll to the bottom, "Usage Notes for Endpoints with Contract Version 3"), there are two solutions to this:

   2a. Don't use those fields (*not an option*)

   2b. Retrieve the problematic fields one by one. BUT I can't do this because neither the ContactUserInfo or ContactRole endpoints are top level entities, meaning I can't make an HTTP request to those endpoints even if I have their id's,

---

3. So I thought maybe I can link the Roles array to the Contact entity instead of the ContactUserInfo entity. I followed the steps [outlined here](https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=709351cc-566a-47b3-b153-3a9fdd690ce0) under **"To Add a Linked or Detail Entity to Another Entity"** but when I get to step 4, my "Insert" button is disabled, preventing me from proceeding.

---

4. I saw a thread somewhere that indicated that perhaps if I fetched the Contacts one by one instead of as a list, the optimization process would be easier and the Roles array would be visible. So I snagged a Contact Id and modified my request to get one Contact instead of a list:

   `{{site}}/entity/Default/18.200.001/Contact/7e87d8fc-6d18-4g95-8334-e54b69e2803t?$expand=UserInfo`

   but now, for some reason, `UserInfo`'s value is `null`. The rest of the fields are the same as when this Contact was in a list, so it's definitely getting the correct data, but now the UserInfo field is null?

## Thank you

Hopefully one of my attempts was on the right track. Happy to provide any additional details upon request.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get specific data that is unavailable in the screen, like the issue you are having, you can build a Generic Inquiry in Acumatica and expose it through web services.

I was able to build a GI joining PX.Objects.CR.Contact, PX.SM.Users, and PX.SM.UsersInRoles and then filtering by the RoleName being equal to Sales Reps (if you check from schema, you can browse to the role). Next, add all of the columns you want to the GI that you want on your web service. Ensure you check the box Visible in the UI on the Generic Inquiry, and test your data through visiting the created GI.

From there, you can follow Diane Cawley's blog on how to expose the GI through web services.

https://www.acumatica.com/blog/contract-based-apis-in-generic-inquiries/